# How do I make a request to an external site from a content_script

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome-extension, same-origin-policy, content-script

I am trying to make a chrome extension that will display a popup in my Gmail that will contain some information from my external server, say today's weather.

**What I have tried**

1. I have tried including the js in the chrome extension, but then trying to make an AJAX call to my server violates the same-origin policy. So that option didn't work.
2. So then I tried keeping my js file on the server and loading it on page load.

My manifest.json looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "cvnosnvsdionfois",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "sldnfksdngsdngods",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "images/icon.png"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "http://api.flickr.com/", "webRequest",
    "tabs", 
    "http://*localhost:8080*"
  ],
 "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://mail.google.com/*"],
      "js": ["http://localhost:8080/static/response.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

I have read elsewhere that Content scripts cannot be included from an external URL, so I figure that this will not work. What is the right approach here. How can I have some javascript code that runs in Gmail, that can request information from my server? For example, how does [Smartr](https://www.xobni.com/download/gmail) do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ain't sure why [Cross-Origin XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr.html) did not work because Extensions aren't so limited like Regular web pages that can use the [XMLHttpRequest](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/) object to send and receive data from remote servers and are limited by the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).  An extension can talk to remote servers outside of its origin, as long as it first requests cross-origin permissions.

### References:

- [Cross-Origin XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr.html)
- [Permissions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest.html#permissions)

### Demonstration

This sample code uses background page to make XHR for another domain.

#### manifest.json

I ensure manifest has all permissions available and also registered a background page.

```
{
  "name": "Demo",
  "description": "Sample Message Communication",
  "version": "1",
  "permissions": [
    "<all_urls>"
   ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },

  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

#### background.js

This sample code make a request for some random asp page

```
function makeXHR() {

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function (data) {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            if (xhr.status == 200) {
                  console.log("Response is received");
            }
        } else {
            //callback(null);
        }
    }

    var url = 'http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp';
    xhr.open('GET', url, true);
    xhr.send();

}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", makeXHR);
```